# Problem while highlighting repeated sentence in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highlight

I want to mark some repeated sentences from a text area input paragraph. I tried the below code but it's not working.

```
highlightRepeated(str) {
  // Split the string into an array of sentences
  const sentences = str.split(".");
  // Create a variable to store the repeated sentences
  let repeated = [];

  // Iterate over the array of sentences
  for (let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    const sentence = sentences[i].trim();
    // If the sentence has already been added to the repeated array, highlight it
    if (repeated.includes(sentence)) {
      sentences[i] = `<mark>${sentence}</mark>`;
    } else {
      // Otherwise, add it to the repeated array
      repeated.push(sentence);
    }
  }

  // Return the modified string
  return sentences.join(".");
},
```

Comment: How are you using this function output? How is it triggered?

Comment: ` handleHighlight() {
      // Get the value of the textarea input field
     const str = this.$refs.input.value;
      
      // Highlight the repeated sentences
      const highlighted = this.highlightRepeated(str);

      // Update the data property with the highlighted string
      this.input = highlighted;
    }`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet works for me. See if you want to use v-html. Or how the function is being called.

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      msg: 'Hello'
    }
  },
    computed: {
    highlightedText(){
      const hlt = this.highlightRepeated(this.msg);
      console.log(hlt);
      return hlt;
    }
  },
  methods:{
    highlightRepeated(str) {
      // Split the string into an array of sentences
      const sentences = str.split(".");
      // Create a variable to store the repeated sentences
      let repeated = [];

      // Iterate over the array of sentences
      for (let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        const sentence = sentences[i].trim();
        // If the sentence has already been added to the repeated array, highlight it
        if (repeated.includes(sentence)) {
          sentences[i] = `<mark>${sentence}</mark>`;
        } else {
          // Otherwise, add it to the repeated array
          repeated.push(sentence);
        }
      }
      // Return the modified string
      return sentences.join(".");
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h1 v-html="highlightedText"></h1>

  <input v-model="msg">
</template>
```

[playground link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Hey brother,Thank u so much. It works fine. But i  need to highlight in texarea field. If i want to search after put some repeated sentence in textarea then show mark tag not highlighted. 

Here is my code
`handleHighlight() {
      // Get the value of the textarea input field
     const str = this.$refs.input.value;
      
      // Highlight the repeated sentences
      const highlighted = this.highlightRepeated(str);

      // Update the data property with the highlighted string
      this.input = highlighted;
    },`

Comment: Input does not render html if that is what you are trying to do. You have to build a custom text area which accepts html as input and use that instead of standard text input component.